# Heroku cannot find module 'Sequelize'

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm getting the error heroku cannot find module 'Sequelize' when the server runs npm start on index.js file. When I run it locally by command heroku local it works fine. What I don't understand is that there is no module called 'Sequelize' in my project. It's called in lower case sequelize. Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "anonbay",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "social network app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "saud",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.3",
    "graphql": "^0.9.1",
    "graphql-subscriptions": "^0.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.7",
    "pg": "^6.1.2",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^3.30.4",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.6.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My bad I was importing 'Sequelize' with uppercase. It works locally but it seems heroku is case sensitive. Changed it to 'sequelize' and it worked